# How to recognize barcodes in a PDF file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pdf

I have a PDF file with n pages, I need to split it to n files. On each page I have barcode, I need to recognize/read barcode. If I have two files with the same barcode I need to merge them.

Can anyone recommend an .net component or exe or something else that will help me? It can be commercial.

I have tried:

- itextsharp - only split and merge files
- dotimage/aspose/idautomation - only recognize barcodes and it very expensive
- a-pdf - not always recognize the barcode and not merge/split two files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

YOu will need at least two and probably even 3 frameworks.

I would use itextsharp to write out the pdf.

You could look at [pdfviewernet](http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewernet/) to read.

And I would look at [vintasoft](http://www.vintasoft.com/) for a cheap(ish) barcodereader.

Answer (score 1):

You may try Aspose.Pdf for .NET along with Aspose.BarCode for .NET in order to achieve your goal quite comfortably:

1. [Split PDF pages](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/split-pdf-to-individual-pages-using-file-paths-facades.html)
2. [Recognize bar codes](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.barcode-for-.net/working-with-barcode-recognition.html)
3. [Merge PDF files/pages into a single PDF file](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/concatenate-pdf-files-using-file-paths-facades.html)

Both of these components work for any .NET Framework version on both 32-bit/64-bit systems. You can use them with any type of .NET application. The APIs are very simple and easy to learn and implement. You might get the idea from the above mentioned samples.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.